# Spring Boot org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, testing

I work to test a RESTful API and the test method is provided,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AppointmentAPITest {


    /*
     * we need a system to simulate this behavior without starting a
     * full HTTP server. MockMvc is the Spring class that does that.
     * */
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private AppointmentAPI api;


    @Test
    public void getAppointments_findById() throws Exception {


        Appointment appoint1 = new Appointment(Date.valueOf("2018-09-01"), Time.valueOf("01:12:16"), "Vania Vong", 125.5);
        Appointment appoint2 = new Appointment(Date.valueOf("2018-10-15"), Time.valueOf("08:30:00"), "Maria Wang", 275);


        given(api.findById(1L)).willReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(appoint1));
        given(api.findById(2L)).willReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(appoint2));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/appointments/1")

                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name_of_doctor", is(appoint1.getName_of_doctor())));
    }}
```

The entity is provided below,

```
@Entity
public class Appointment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private java.sql.Time created_at;

    @Column
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private java.sql.Date appointment_date;

    @Column
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    private String name_of_doctor;

    @Embedded
    private Status status;

    @Column
    private double price;

    public Appointment() {

    }

    public Appointment(Date appointment_date, Time created_at, String name_of_doctor, double price) {

        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.appointment_date = appointment_date;
        this.name_of_doctor = name_of_doctor;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Appointment(String name_of_doctor, Status status, double price) {

        this.name_of_doctor = name_of_doctor;
        this.status = status;
        this.price = price;
    }


    public Appointment(String name_of_doctor, double price) {

        this.name_of_doctor = name_of_doctor;
        this.price = price;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Time getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(Time created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public Date getAppointment_date() {
        return appointment_date;
    }

    public void setAppointment_date(Date appointment_date) {
        this.appointment_date = appointment_date;
    }

    public String getName_of_doctor() {
        return name_of_doctor;
    }

    public void setName_of_doctor(String name_of_doctor) {
        this.name_of_doctor = name_of_doctor;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Appointment)) return false;
        Appointment that = (Appointment) o;
        return Double.compare(that.getPrice(), getPrice()) == 0 &&
                Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId()) &&
                Objects.equals(getCreated_at(), that.getCreated_at()) &&
                Objects.equals(getAppointment_date(), that.getAppointment_date()) &&
                Objects.equals(getName_of_doctor(), that.getName_of_doctor()) &&
                Objects.equals(getStatus(), that.getStatus());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(getId(), getCreated_at(), getAppointment_date(), getName_of_doctor(), getStatus(), getPrice());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Appointment{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", created_at=" + created_at +
                ", appointment_date=" + appointment_date +
                ", name_of_doctor='" + name_of_doctor + '\'' +
                ", status=" + status +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The API end-point is provided below,

```
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("/api/v1/appointments")

public class AppointmentAPI {


    @Autowired
    AppointmentServiceImpl service;
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Appointment> findById(@PathVariable Long id) {


        Optional<Appointment> appointment = service.findById(id);

        if (!appointment.isPresent()) {
            ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(appointment.get());
    }



   // ..............
   }
```

When I run the test, I get the error provided,

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument type [java.lang.Long] not available, and parameter name information not found in class file either.

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
    at com.appoint.manager.Appointment.api.AppointmentAPITest.getAppointments_findById(AppointmentAPITest.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument type [java.lang.Long] not available, and parameter name information not found in class file either.
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.updateNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:172)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.getNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    ... 51 more
```

Why does it saying the Name for argument type [java.lang.Long] not available, and parameter name information not found in class?

Comment: show your request mapping for /api/v1/appointments/

Comment: @MaciejKowalski its provided now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the name to the annotation in the method parameter:

```
findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id)
```

Comment: This is already there `public ResponseEntity<Appointment> findById(@PathVariable Long id)`. Do you mean I need to add the method parameter in the test method as well? 

I tried it and that doesn't work out.

Comment: Just the name attribute of @PathVariable